# android sqlite query error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this code to check if the values of (lang) and (lat) exist or not. If they don't exist the program crashed instead of the function returning true. Why?

```
public boolean pointNotExist(int lat, int lang)
{
    Cursor r= db.query(DATABASE_TABLE3, new String[] {
                    "_id",
                    "point_name",
                    "point_langtitude",
                    "point_latitude",
                    "No_of_visits"
                    }, 
                "point_langtitude"+"=" +lang+ " and " +"point_latitude"+ "="+lat,
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    if(r==null)
    {
        r.close();
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        r.moveToFirst();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("No_of_visits", 7);
        boolean d=db.update(DATABASE_TABLE3, args, 
        "_id"  + "=" + r.getInt(0), null) > 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the logCat :

```
ERROR/Database(32321): 
    Error inserting points_counter=2 point_langtitude=-10084093 _id=16 point_latitude=37422005 
ERROR/Database(32321):   
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

The inserting Points_Counter is a counter in another class and when this counter =2 this (pointNotExist) function invoked.
*The problem occurred before else statement.*

This is the inserting code:

```
public void insertPointOfIntrest(int lat, int lang,String name)
{ 
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
    initialValues.put("point_langtitude", lang); 
    initialValues.put("point_latitude", lat); 
    initialValues.put("point_name", name); 
    initialValues.put("No_of_visits",1); 
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, initialValues); 
}
```

This is the creating table code:

```
//creating table 
track_pointOfInterest db.execSQL(
        "create table pointOfIntrest (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        +"point_name text," 
        + "point_langtitude integer, point_latitude integer, " 
        + "No_of_visits );"
    );
```

Comment: this is the logCat     :                   ERROR/Database(32321): Error inserting points_counter=2 point_langtitude=-10084093 _id=16 point_latitude=37422005 ERROR/Database(32321): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this.

long d=db.update(DATABASE_TABLE3, args, 
                    "_id"  + "=" + r.getInt(0), null) > 0;

Comment: the compiler ask me to change type to boolean ,but anyway this is not the problem ,the problem occurred before else statement

Comment: can you paste your full DB source code? because "Error inserting points_counter=2" where is points_counter and also tell inserting? so ..

Comment: this is the inserting code : public void insertPointOfIntrest(int lat, int lang,String name){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("point_langtitude", lang);
        initialValues.put("point_latitude", lat);
        initialValues.put("point_name", name);
        initialValues.put("No_of_visits",1);
         db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, initialValues);
        }

Comment: this is the creating table code: //creating table track_pointOfInterest
            db.execSQL("create table pointOfIntrest  (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
              +"point_name text,"
                    + "point_langtitude integer, point_latitude integer, " +
            "No_of_visits );");

Comment: the inserting Points_Counter is a counter in another class and when this counter =2 this (pointNotExist) function invoked

Comment: @Nik.... the points_counter is a counter in another class and when its =2 this function (pointNotExist) invoked

Comment: please any help I need this in my graduation